# Maven with quarkus "java.lang.StackOverflowerror"

Tags: maven, jenkins, quarkus

Am stuck with an issue. I am using jenkins agent and when ever I run mvn package it gives error "java.lang.stackoverflowerror". I need permanent solution for this error, logs shown below:-

```
[DEBUG] incrementalBuildHelper#beforeRebuildExecution
[INFO] Compiling 99 source files to /target/classes
An exception has occurred in the compiler (17.0.8.1). Please file a bug against the Java compiler via the Java bug reporting page (https://bugreport.java.com) after checking the Bug Database (https://bugs.java.com) for duplicates. Include your program, the following diagnostic, and the parameters passed to the Java compiler in your report. Thank you.
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribExpr(Attr.java:730)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitBinary(Attr.java:3975)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCBinary.accept(JCTree.java:2156)
```

I tried delete .m2 folder (no gain) but when tried increasing stack -Xss1024m, sometimes it builds but most of the time crashes.

Comment: Please give more information about your project.... the used MVN Version, Plugins versions etc. also your pom file ...